# Linq access object field

Tags: linq, linqpad

I am trying to query data with Linq using LinqPad, update it and submit changes back to database. Unfortunately I get error on `myobject.Email` that `Email` field is not exists. Why I can't access `Email` field?

```
var myobject = from u in Users where u.Email == "myolde@email.com" select u;
myobject.First();
myobject.Email = "mynew@mail.com";
SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access collection's field. You might want to access first object:

```
var myObject = from u in Users where u.Email == "myolde@email.com" select u;
var user = myobject.First();
user.Email = "mynew@mail.com";
SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: My mistake, SubmitChanges is database object method not query object.

Comment: I just confused that there is no brackets. As far as I understand you're using C#.